Lenovo Thinkpad Z16 gen 1 booted by Ubuntu-20.04 LTS USB media error
I am not able to boot into desktop of Ubuntu-20.04 LTS with USB media on my Lenovo Thinkpad Z16 gen 1. I tried multiple times with different USB drives(Sandisk cruzer and SanDisk Extreme pro) but still returned errors in attached screenshots.
The Secure boot setting also changed to disabled in BIOS/UEFI.
How can I boot into desktop of Ubuntu-20.04 LTS with USB media on my Lenovo Thinkpad Z16 gen 1?
Thank you!
ref:
https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops?q=Z16&limit=20&category=Laptop&vendor=Lenovo&release=20.04+LTS
Lenovo Thinkpad Z16 gen 1 is Ubuntu certified laptop that can run the Ubuntu release 20.04 LTS.
[
